# setInterval of a private function

Tags: javascript

i want to do a setInterval of a function that is at the same level as the declaration of the setinterval but not global

**Example:**

```
function a()
{
    function b(){alert("hi");}
    setInterval("b()",1000);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, simply use `setInterval(b, 1000)` instead of `setInterval("b()", 1000)`.

I'd go as far as to say you should *always* use `setInterval` and `setTimeout` with a real function instead of a string.

Comment: You should do this anyway, not just in the example.

Comment: function f(){function a(){}function b(){setInterval(a,100);}}